# How to get the directory of database?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am using the Microsoft database that is inside `C:\wpf1\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1` folder. When I update the database it always updates the one inside `C:\wpf1\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\bin\Debug` which I don't want.

How do I get the folder `C:\wpf1\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1` without typing this full name?

Comment: What's a “Microsof database”? Do you mean MS SQL Server? How is the code you posted relevant to database access?

Comment: it is in same folder as App.xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory `C:\wpf1\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1` is your project directory - its the one that the source code is in, but its not normally a directory that your application would usually be aware of or work with (for example if your application is installed to another PC then this directory simply won't exist).

The usual approach when working with databases or dependent files is to either:

- Put the file in some other common location (such as in a folder on the `C:` drive)
- Just have the application work with the copy of the file in the output (`bin\Debug\`) directory, i.e. the directory that the application will be installed to - you can change the properties of the item in your solution to have the item copied to the output directory, either all the time or only when the item in the solution directory is newer:

[image: Screenshot of the properties pane for a project item in Visual Studio]

If you *really* want to use `C:\wpf1\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1` directory then the way to do it is to assume that this directory will always be 2 higher than the current working directory:

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "..\\.."));
```

This of course makes 2 horrible assumptions, first that the current directory is the directory that the .exe is contained in, and secondly that the directory you want is always 2 higher than this directory - I strongly recommend that you find another way as this sort of logic is highly unlikely to work on an end-users PC.

Comment: I don't have GetFullPath, Combine inside WPF, maybe this is forms only, but thx i get the idea.

Comment: This will work but be careful when you come to deploy it to your users as it almost certainly wont work then.

Answer (score 1):

There is an article here [about sql server compact edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219485%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

I dont think anything has changed in the newer releases although it is a while since i have used it.

|DataDirectory| works as follows

Your connection string would normally look like this
“Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Mydb.sdf”

To set the DataDirectory property, call the AppDomain.SetData method.

If you do not set the DataDirectory property, the following default rules will be applied to access the database folder:

For applications that are put in a folder on the user's computer, the database folder uses the application folder. (this is the default rule that applies when debugging and hence why the database in \bin\debug is the one that is updated)

For applications that are running under ClickOnce, the database folder uses the specific data folder that is created.

In the past i have done the following

Handle the SettingsLoaded event in settings.vb

```
        Private Sub MySettings_SettingsLoaded(sender As Object, e As System.Configuration.SettingsLoadedEventArgs) Handles Me.SettingsLoaded

        If Not Debugger.IsAttached Then
            My.Settings.SQLCEConnectionString = "somefolder\somefile.sdf"
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: this doesn't works for me, i don't find any DataDirectory, maybe because i don't use northwind